# Scaling backround like ImageView scaleType="fitCenter"

Tags: android, kotlin, background, imageview, scaling

I have ImageView that great scale my file.png with scaleType = "fitCenter" by keeping it rectangular and making smaller/bigger on diffrent screens/rotations.
This ImageView is inside LinearLayout with the same background file.
The problem is, I cannot get the same result after scaling with background - always source picture gets streched horizantaly or gets bigger.

Here is code i have:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_button_quiz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/scaling_background">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_quiz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/brain_off"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is solution of backgroud scaling i tried, that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/brain_off"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

To sum it up:
I want background of my LinearLayout to scale the same as ImageView that is inside it, that is scaleType=fitCenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center|fill"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />
</item>
```

set this as background of your layout. But this will fill the background and image may stretch.
to make it work perfectly set background programmatically

```
int widthI = bitMapin.getWidth();
int heightI = bitMapin.getHeight();
int widthC = container.getWidth();
int heightC = container.getHeight();
int new_width = widthC;
int new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) heightI *( (double) new_width / (double)       widthI ));
Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitMapin, new_width, new_height, true);
container.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), newbitMap))
```

Comment: OK, I'm still learning basics so please excuse me for probably noob question, but how do I put this <item> into xml file? Isn't it just for menu or selectors?

Comment: Ok, put inside <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > and put file in drawable folder